# how to send cookie with cmd curl?

Tags: php, curl

I have an API for an mobile app. One of the API function is to sign in the user. When user is signed in he can access other API functions. I do this by tracking user session. But here is my problem I am testing API with curl and I can get it to work. I tried accessing API with browser and it worked but when I try with command line curl it doesnt, so I think curl doesnt send cookie. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say curl where to save and load cookies: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html (Chapter 10)

For you it must be `curl --cookie cookies.txt --cookie-jar newcookies.txt         http://www.example.com` where `--cookie` tells curl where to load cookies and `--cookie-jar` where to save cookies. Those files can be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "fruit=apple; colour=red");
```